# php file_get_contents strange characters

Tags: html, file-get-contents, invalid-characters

As normally I would use fil_get_contents to get the html structure of a certain page
but with a particular site I have tried all I get instead of the html structure is
characters like these:

J��t��`$ؐ@������iG#)�*��eVe]f@�흼

Does anyone have any idea what it might be? I am wondering the site
has a protective system that detects whether a request is made by
a real user or a php script and in the second case it displays this.

I have used curl to get the page and specified browser agent but I guess
I should take it further by using curl cookies or more....

the function I use (curl version):

```
function getPage($url) {

    $proxies = array();
    $proxies[] = 'proxies here';


    if (isset($proxies)) {
        $proxy = $proxies[array_rand($proxies)];
    }


    $ch = curl_init();

    $header = array(
        'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12',
        'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5',
        'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate',
        'Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7',
        'Keep-Alive: 115',
        'Connection: keep-alive');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    return $result;
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us the code that you're using to get the content?

Comment: [Mastering UTF-8 encoding in PHP and MySQL](http://blog.flowl.info/2014/mastering-unicodeutf-8-encoding-php/)

Comment: maybe the site has some other charset

Comment: it would help a lot to see what particular site you are talking about.

Comment: In my browser i can view it normally. *the page source

Comment: The website is in english and I dont see any charset speficication on the html structure

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're dealing with character encoding the [iconv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) function may help you.